# Enabling gzip on AWS Elastic Beanstalk doesn't take effect

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.tonmoygoswami.com/2013/05/how-to-enable-gzip-on-amazon-elastic.html) to enable gzip compression on my Spring Boot project (version 1.5.3) on AWS Elastic Beanstalk with Tomcat.
I put the .ebextensions folder under src/main/webapps directory, and in the war file i created, it resides on top level as it should be.

After deploying and restarting the app servers, i performed the [Http Compression Test](http://www.whatsmyip.org/http-compression-test/)
but it resulted that my application is NOT compressed. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the logs to validate there were no errors in the extensions?